# tree implementation in buffer of fixed size

Tags: c++, c, tree

Which open source implementations of a tree (with arbitrary number of children per node; nodes containing a small data type like int or a pointer (additional to the implementation-specific indexing data, of course)) in a (linear) buffer do exist? (Obviously, the maximum number of tree nodes is bounded by the buffer size)

(Graph instead of tree would also be okay).

Comment: there's a boost::graph for graphs but it would be like killing a sparrow with a nuke :)

Comment: With an arbitrary number of children? A binary tree is quite simple, I was not aware that there is simple implementation for an arbitrary number of children unless the nodes in the fixed buffer contain more complex data which indexes it's children. Will be interesting to see the answers to this.

Comment: May I ask what you intend to do with this tree?  I had similar ideas for serializing compiler intermediate data long ago.  Doing it this way in C++ might cause problems since it might try to hide pointers within classes where you don't expect them.  You'll also have to reference by _BASE_ + _index_ rather than by pointer.

Comment: What underlying problem are you trying to solve here that isn't handled by a normal tree? A little more context would help us with solutions (or is this strictly theoretical?).

Answer (score 0):

You can take any implementation of a tree that allows a stateful allocator, and implement a custom allocator on top of your fixed size buffer.

Though the C++ standard doesn't guarantee support for stateful allocators, they work "with most STL implementations most of the time". Allocator state is usually only a problem when moving nodes between containers.

If you can live with one instance, the buffer can also be a template parameter.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, but I suspect that the OP wants one that stores the child references as indexes rather than pointers so that the tree could be easily serialized or moved within RAM.  The implementation of an existing C++ template would have to be specially designed to allow for non-pointer reference values.  I don't doubt that such a thing exists, perhaps even overloading the urinary `&` and `*` operators and using a custom type for references (or even an iterator, perhaps), but that is a tall order.

Comment: @nategoose: I really hope you mean *unary* `&` and `*`.

Comment: a custom allocator could be designed to use indices as pointers, though I'm not sure if an STL allocator can do that.

Comment: @bk1e: Um...  I am embarrassed.  Yes, I meant _unary_.